# How to assign different image views in each item of the spinner?

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-imageview

I want to display different image views in each items in my `spinner` and indicate their position. My problem is, the `spinner` can only display one `ImageView`.

```java
states = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Facilities);
imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.popup);

image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.country_image);
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country_spinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               int position, long id) {
        image.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(
                spinner.getSelectedItemPosition(), -1));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I have indented your code sample so that it renders properly.

Comment: can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Custom Adapter and inflate custom layout with it

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/position"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Following is the CustomAdaoter which inflates the above layout in spinner

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context context;
    int images[];

    public CustomAdapter(Context ctx, int txtViewResourceId, String[] objects, int[] images)
    {
        super(ctx, txtViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context=ctx;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return customView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return customView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View customView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        TextView imgPosition = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.position);
        imgPosition.setText(position);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        return convertView;

    }
      //Override the getCount() because we are passing object as null in constructor
      //getCount() determines how many times the getView should b called
    @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

}
```

Call it in the Activity in which you want to show the spinner

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    int imgData[] = {R.drawable.ic_action_alarms,R.drawable.ic_action_discard,R.drawable.ic_launcher};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.row,null,imgData);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Implement the method CustomView as follows:

```
public View customView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        return convertView;

    }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at the  imageView.setImageResource(images[Int.toString(position)]);

specifically at the 'Int'

Comment: sorry it was a typo...i have edited it...enjoy... :)...accept answer if u may ;)

Comment: will this set different images in different positions?

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? all the pictures in one row ?

Comment: no .. i want to display one picture at a time having different positions ..please help.

Comment: ok you want one picture to be right aligned and other to be left aligned..something like that ??

Comment: yes and no. can i just send you a photo? what's your email?

Comment: i want my pictures to be displayed in different positions.. can i put image views in each item?

Comment: yes you can, if you want two images in one item then add another ImageView in row.xml..and repeat the process of binding it..

Comment: i only need to put one image in one item .. but i need to put each item an image view..

Comment: my dear please post the pic or if you can't post it here, email me at niazee@gmail.com...it will save both of us a lot of time.

Comment: Just Comment the follwoing in the code...you will have only image in the spinner item

TextView imgPosition = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.position);
        imgPosition.setText(position);

Comment: where should i comment this?

Comment: our app is a vicinity map.
the idea is that when user clicks a item from a spinner, location should appear on top of the user's chosen item..

example.. the user chooses a specific building from the list of items in the spinner, an icon should appear to indicate its location

Comment: remove textView from row.xml...then it wont force close

Comment: it should not crash, however check my edited answer :)

Comment: i already checked it .. it's still the same .can you give me a code  that sets the different image views in each item of a spinner?

Comment: copy your images in the Drawable folder then...
in the code 
int imgData[] = {R.drawable.yourimage1,R.drawable.yourimage2......so on};

Comment: nice to hear that ! :)

Comment: crash `java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null`